# Get AspNet.ApplicationCookie using javascript

Tags: javascript, .net, cookies

I have no idea is this possible, but I have to ask. Is there a way to get AspNet.ApplicationCookie from Cookies.

I have tried:

```
`$.cookie('.AspNet.ApplicationCookie');`

`document.cookie;`

document.cookie.AspNet.ApplicationCookie;
```

Hope someone knows :D

Comment: It is possible if you disable the server side security feature making it not possible as per regularmikes answer but doing so is a very bad idea if you haven't thought it through. Allowing client side scripts to read authentication cookies means they can also also be stolen by for example: people injecting nefarious scripts into urls for your site that they then email to users of your site. When the users of your site click the link while logged in, the script can then read their authentication cookie and send it off to the "evil doer" who can then hijack the users session.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to access it, but you have to explicitly allow it in the cookie authentication options. For me, this normally means opening Startup.Auth.cs in the App_Start folder and setting the `CookieHttpOnly` option to `false` in the `CookieAuthenticationOptions` object. In a new MVC 5 application using the template it should look like this:

```
app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
{          
    CookieHttpOnly = false, // this option is necessary to allow JavaScript access
    AuthenticationType = DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie,
    LoginPath = new PathString("/Account/Login"),                       
    Provider = new CookieAuthenticationProvider
    {                    
        OnValidateIdentity = SecurityStampValidator.OnValidateIdentity<ApplicationUserManager, ApplicationUser>(
            validateInterval: TimeSpan.FromMinutes(30),
            regenerateIdentity: (manager, user) => user.GenerateUserIdentityAsync(manager))                       
    },                
});
```

Comment: This is something I would definitely NOT recommend. By making the auth cookie NOT an HTTPCookie, it will allow reading of the cookie via javascript, which i appreciate is the OPs intent, but it will also significantly increase risk associated with cross site scripting attack vectors.